# list[var-1] gets last instead of throwing IndexError?

Tags: python, list, indexing, index-error

I know this could quite possibly be a relatively simple question to answer, but I have been stuck on it for a little time now. I am creating a maze solving algorithm in Python. The maze is formed like so (0 = wall, 1 = space). I store each row as a nested list:

```
data = [
         [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
         [0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],
         [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
         [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0],
         [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
         [0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],
         [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
         [0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
         [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],
         [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
        ]
```

For easier viewing, my program translates that data into this:

```
◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎   ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎
◼︎       ◼︎   ◼︎       ◼︎
◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎
◼︎   ◼︎       ◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎
◼︎   ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎
◼︎       ◼︎   ◼︎       ◼︎
◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎   ◼︎
◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎       ◼︎   ◼︎
◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎   ◼︎   ◼︎
◼︎   ◼︎       ◼︎       ◼︎
◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎   ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎ ◼︎
```

Finding a space's `surrounding_spaces` is crucial to the success of my program as I use it to find dead ends. However, the openings of the maze could be considered a dead end by the program because there is only one way to get to the opening. To combat this, I rely on the program throwing an `IndexError` in `get_surrounding()` so that one of the items in the opening's `surrounding_spaces` is `None`.

In `main()`, I iterate over each space that is equal to `1` which is a valid space the program can take.

```
def main():
    row_ind = 0
    for row in data:
        space_ind = 0
        for space in row:
            if space == 1:
                get_surrounding(row_ind, space_ind)
            space_ind += 1
        row_ind += 1
```

In `get_surrounding()`, I create a `list` with the `surrounding_spaces` of the current `row`. This is where I am relying on the `IndexError` so that the program becomes aware that it is an opening and not a dead end:

```
def get_surrounding(row, space):
    try:
        left = data[row][space - 1]
    except:
        left = None
    try:
        right = data[row][space + 1]
    except:
        right = None
    try:
        up = data[row - 1][space]
    except:
        up = None
    try:
        down = data[row + 1][space]
    except:
        down = None

    surrounding_spaces = [left, right, up, down]
    print("[" + str(row) + ", " + str(space) + "]:" + str(surrounding_spaces))
```

The output of this is entirely correct. The `surrounding_spaces` of the opening in the last `row` of `data` is: `[0, 0, 1, None]`

However, the top row is an exception (`data[0]`). It **does** have an opening at `data[0][7]`. When the `up` variable is set in `get_surrounding()`, it treats the **first row** as the **last row** because `data[row-1][space]`, which is essentially `data[-1][space]` as `row = 0`. Using `-1` as an index gets the `last` item of a `list`, and I do not want to treat it as the last `row`. In my case, when the `top row` is iterated over, I want `data[row-1][space]` to throw an `IndexError`, because there is no `row` in `data` before `row0[0]`. If there is an easier way to accomplish this, any suggestions are welcomed.

**Desired Output**

```
[0, 7]:[0, 0, None, 1]
[10, 5]:[0, 0, 1, None]
```

**Actual Output**

```
# lists are formed like so: [left, right, up, down]
# the up value in the first list should be None, but it is 0 because when the up value is set the program treated  
[0, 7]:[0, 0, 0, 1]
[10, 5]:[0, 0, 1, None]
```

**Note**

To translate the data for easier viewing, I used a custom class:

```
class MazeData:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def display(self):
        data = self.data
        length = len(data[0])
        prettified_data = []
        space_ids = {0:"◼︎", 1:" ", 2:"@", 3:"•"}
        for row in data:
            line = []
            for space in row:
                line.append(space_ids.get(space))
            prettified_data.append(line)

        for row in prettified_data:
            print(" ".join(row))
```

You can initialize and display a board this way:

```
board = MazeData(data)
board.display()
```

Comment: "I want data[row-1][space] to throw an IndexError" - well, it won't. Python culture might be okay with relying on exceptions for control flow, but that doesn't make it mandatory. You *can* just check the bounds yourself.

Comment: Gotcha. When you say "check the bounds yourself", I am assuming you mean just explicitly check if the space is in `data[0]`? Thank you guys for your response.

Comment: Consider using one-fourth as many items in the matrix, and have each cell be a 4-bit quantity indicating which of the 4 directions are open.